# How to track a subdomain's data with google analytics

Tags: seo

I have my site [here](http://www.queenofthedesert.ca/) and I would like to track it's visits however the code I have in there now is not working (I've had it successfully"tracking" for days now but no data has been shown.

I've purchased a domain name and am pointing it to a subdomain of a hosting account I have. I've followed tutorials & read articles, but almost everything is outdated and it's not even working. What is a good method of setting up google analytics for a sub domain that a newbie with google analytics can follow or understand?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-32557751-2']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'priscilla.ambergoodwin.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'ambergoodwin.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

I have my website account and then I've added a profile to it called "sub domain tracking" & given it a fliter. Below are the images of my account and profile and settings for the filter.

[image]

[image]

So I just dont understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try creating a new site in your analytics account with your new subdomain included in the url...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Layton. If you see my questions I added some images as to how I've set it up.

Comment: Set the subdomain's url to subdomain.yourdomain.com rather than www.yourdomain.com?  Its been a while since I have used analytics, I just know that I would treat each subdomain as a separate site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to track sub-domain is to add new website under this account and generate new analytics code for this sub-domain only. Just insert the newly created code into all pages of this sub-domain and it will start working fine for sure.

Regarding to same account; it will be complex process and you will have to follow different steps provided here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Googling this before you posted here? There are lots of resources on how to track subdomains. Here's one: http://theanalyticsguru.wordpress.com/2008/03/01/tracking-subdomains-within-google-analytics/

In short - it's not a filter within your site, it's a completely new site.